# Removing commas from numbers with .NET regex

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm processing a report that (brilliantly, really) spits out number values with commas in them, in a .csv output. Super useful.

So, I'm using (C#)regex lookahead positive and lookbehind positive expressions to remove commas that have digits on both sides.

If I use only the lookahead, it seems to work. However when I add the lookbehind as well, the expression breaks down and removes nothing. Both ends of the comma can have arbitrary numbers of digits around them, so I just want to remove the comma if the pattern has one or more digits around it.

Here's the expression that works with the lookahead only:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[,](?=(\d+)),"");
```

Here's the expression that doesn't work as I intend it:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[,](?=(\d+)?<=(\d+))", "");
```

What's wrong with my regex! If I had to guess, there's something I'm misunderstanding about how lookbehind works. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea, but I would suggest `Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d),(\d)", "$1$2")`

Comment: How would you know if `1,2,3,4` is `1, 2, 3, 4` or `1.2, 3.4` or `1, 2.3, 4` or some other combination?

Comment: This whole idea might be useless if you don't have another separator than a comma or at least the values in some kind of quotes (see Andreas' commen)t. An if you have that, then the simple regex of Slai is sufficient.

Comment: I agree with Andreas. That ambiguity is going to mean you will need to solve the original problem. The thing which creates that CSV file isn't actually creating a valid CSV file, because it should have quoted the values containing commas. If you can't fix that, maybe you can trick it by running it in a locale which uses dot as the decimal point.

Comment: You may try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\d),(?=\d)", string.Empty)`, but it seems the original approach might need re-considering.

Comment: Well it's using the comma as a thousands separator, not a decimal point. It does surround the numbers with quotes, but it's easier to strip out the commas IMHO.

Comment: It would help if you can you show an example input and the required output

Comment: @Scuba Steve Then it should be enough if you just search for the number-comma-number pattern and remove the comma. I didn't intefere with C# yet, but Slai's solution looks like it should work.

Comment: there is also a bit overlooked minor detail that for thousands separator it is 3 digits after the comma, and not more than 3 digits before the comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use any of the solutions below:

```
var s = "abc,def,2,100,xyz!,:))))";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d),(\d)", "$1$2"));   // Does not handle 1,2,3,4 cases
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d),(?=\d)", "$1"));   // Handles consecutive matches with capturing group+backreference/lookahead
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\d),(?=\d)", ""));  // Handles consecutive matches with lookbehind/lookahead, the most efficient way
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @",(?<=\d,)(?=\d)", "")); // Also handles all cases
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/NxfDfN).

**Explanations**:

- `(\d),(\d)` - matches and captures single digits on both sides of `,` and `$1$2` are replacement backreferences that insert captured texts back into the result
- `(\d),(?=\d)` - matches and captures a digit before `,`, then a comma is matched and then a positive lookahead `(?=\d)` requires a digit after `,`, but since it is not consumed, onyl `$1` is required in the replacement pattern
- `(?<=\d),(?=\d)` - only such a comma is matched that is enclosed with digits without consuming the digits (`(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind that requires its pattern match immediately to the left of the current location)
- `,(?<=\d,)(?=\d)` - matches a comma and only after matching it, the regex engine checks if there is a digit and a comma immediately before the location (that is after the comma), and if the check if true, the next char is checked for a digit. If it is a digit, a match is returned.

[RegexHero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/) test:

[image]

**Bonus**:

You may just match a pattern like yours with `\d,\d` and pass the match to the [`MatchEvaluator` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) where you may manipulate the match further:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"\d,\d", m => m.Value.Replace(",",string.Empty))); // Callback method
```

Here, `m` is the match object and `m.Value` holds the whole match value. With `.Replace(",",string.Empty)`, you remove all commas from the match value.

Comment: Awesome answer, very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always check a website that evaluates regex expressions.
I think this code might be able to help you:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[,](?=(\d+))(?<=(\d))", "");
```