# HTML rendering decimal separator as comma in es-colombia

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Version)
```

The original value is 3.5 and it is rendering as 3,5
I tried using lang attribute and pattern.but no use from the controller it is returning properly but in the browser it is displaying differently.

Comment: I am using Chrome browser

Comment: You might try some of the things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020000/can-i-force-the-razor-textboxfor-helper-to-use-a-specific-decimal-separator-than)